# Amazon s3 Image Upload (cognito id null)

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito

Image is not uploading in a amazon s3 . I was using the old library all the upload was working fine but for ios 8 i use new sdk and create new conginito id 
now i am facing errors. any help will be appreciated
My code is

```
  AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest *request = [[AWSS3TransferManagerUploadRequest alloc] init];






    request.bucket = @"my bucket name";
    request.key = @"my cognitio id";
    request.body =[NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
    request.contentType = @"image/png";


    [[transferManager upload:request] continueWithExecutor:[BFExecutor mainThreadExecutor]
                                                 withBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {
                                                     NSLog(@"ckmdkcd dvdsv");
                                                     if (task.error) {
                                                         if ([task.error.domain isEqualToString:AWSS3TransferManagerErrorDomain]) {
                                                             switch (task.error.code) {
                                                                 case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorCancelled:
                                                                 case AWSS3TransferManagerErrorPaused:
                                                                     break;

                                                                 default:
                                                                     NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                                     break;
                                                             }
                                                         } else {
                                                             // Unknown error.
                                                             NSLog(@"Error: %@", task.error);
                                                         }
                                                     }

                                                     if (task.result) {
                                                         AWSS3TransferManagerUploadOutput *uploadOutput = task.result;
                                                         // The file uploaded successfully.


                                                         NSLog(@"result = %@",task.result);
                                                     }
                                                     return nil;
                                                 }];
```

I got the following response

```
AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSIdentityProvider.m line:185 | __51-[AWSAbstractCognitoIdentityProvider getIdentityId]_block_invoke169 | GetId failed. Error is [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1003.)" UserInfo=0x7f9b987aabf0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9b9a839480 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1003.)"}]
2015-04-14 08:13:16.326 newtest[6611:172200] AWSiOSSDKv2 [Error] AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:534 | __40-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider refresh]_block_invoke350 | Unable to refresh. Error is [Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1003.)" UserInfo=0x7f9b987aabf0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9b9a839480 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1003.)"}]
2015-04-14 08:13:16.328 newtest[6611:172071] ckmdkcd dvdsv
2015-04-14 08:13:16.328 newtest[6611:172071] Error: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (NSURLErrorDomain error -1003.)" UserInfo=0x7f9b987aabf0 {NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f9b9a839480 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork error -1003.)"}
```

I am also setting cognitio id in app delegate.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the fact that you seeing `https://cognito-identity.(null).amazonaws.com/` in the error, it would lead me to believe you are not correctly setting the region when creating the `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider`. Please double check that you are not setting this to `AWSRegionUnknown`.

**Update 2015-04-17**: [Here is the list of Region constants](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSiOSSDK/latest/Constants/AWSRegionType.html). You should set this to the region where your identity pool exists. Currently Amazon Cognito is only available in `AWSRegionUSEast1` or `AWSRegionEUWest1`.

Note, the region of your identity pool has nothing to do the region of other AWS services you may use in your application. You can use an identity pool in `AWSRegionUSEast1` to access resources in `AWSRegionSAEast1`, for instance.

Comment: what should I set  instead of this  , to get available for all regions?

Comment: @ZohaibkhanNiazi I've updated my answer with additional info that should answer your question.

Comment: thnks for that let me check it .

Comment: thnks for such a quick response. Now i am facing that problem {__type=InvalidIdentityPoolConfigurationException, message=Invalid identity pool configuration. Check assigned IAM roles for this pool.}]

Comment: actually i am following that tutorial http://mobiletoolworks.com/tutorial-using-amazon-aws-s3-storage-with-your-ios-swift-app/ for configuring cogniito id  and on mobile side i am using s3 transfer manager sample provided by amazon

Comment: @ZohaibkhanNiazi Please make sure your identity pool id matches the identity pool id listed in your roles trust policy, to understand trust policies, you may want to review [this blog post](http://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx1OSMBRHZVM9V0/Understanding-Amazon-Cognito-Authentication-Part-3-Roles-and-Policies). If you have more troubles, please consider opening an issue in our [forums](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/forumfilter.jspa?forumID=173&start=0).